Flyback transformer design
My question is almost similar to the question Google.
The flyback transformer is actually a coupled inductor. So it must be designed like an inductor.
After obtaining the required inductance, it is time to create the values.
There are typically two methods for creating a minimum inductance.
When the core has a gap, it is better to use this formula to achieve the required inductance because ue decreases with increasing gap and consequently AL decreases.

But when the kernel is ungapped. Using the above calculation does not seem logical. Because due to the high ue the number of initial rounds will be very low. I think that is why the following calculation is used.

At the end of each method, it is better to calculate Bmax.
Can anyone explain this issue more clearly and tell me if what I'm saying is incorrect?

In a normal flyback transformer, you are not Bmax limited but rather loss limited. Sure, you need to keep your operating point below Bmax, but at 2024 switching speeds, this shouldn’t be an issue.

I usually start from the MOSFET breakdown voltage to determine the turns ratio of a flyback converter (check my APEC 2011 seminar but also the design example in the more recent one on SIMPLIS).

You are right
But which formula above should be used when?
In all cores, whether iron powder or ferrite, losses become a limiting factor in the design.
Here the issue is to create the values ​​obtained.

All of them? It's a multi-boundary condition equation system. To have a working flyback, you need to gap your core to suitable Al for your circuit to transfer the power needed, wind enough primary turns to not saturate your core and not overheat your winding nor core. Start here: https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/slup127/slup127.pdf

Of course we need gap
I prefer to create the required values ​​with AL and calculate the flux density with the help of ue.ui.H and if it is high, increase the gap or choose a larger core.
